Django conditionally hide form fields
I Have the below form and based on the dropdown value selected by the user, I want to display/ hide some fields. For example, if the user selects EMI from the drop-down, the EMI field from the form will be hidden. How can I achieve this?


Choices = [('emi', 'EMI'),
                      ('roi', 'Rate of Interest'),
                      ('term', 'Term'),
                      ('amount', 'Loan Amount')]

class loanform(forms.Form):
    calculation = forms.CharField(label='What do you want to calculate?', widget=forms.Select(choices=Choices))
    loanAmount = forms.IntegerField(label='Loan Amount')
    roi = forms.FloatField(label='Rate of Interest')
    term = forms.IntegerField(label='Term in months')
    emi = forms.FloatField(label='EMI')




The choice loanform.calculation is part of the form so before choosing, the form is already rendered. You need client side JavaScript to be able to manipulate the form again. But if the choice is part of the request, you will render the form conditionally based on the choice. If you understood the comment but need more clarification, I’ll write an answer.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I understood your comment, It will be helpful if you add some more clarification

I have added an answer. I was wondering if it worked for you? If it didn’t but you found another, please post it so that you can close this question as complete.

Before you render a Django Form, you can manipulate it on the Server however you wish. But after you render it, it can no longer be manipulated by the Server because it has been rendered in HTML and is in the hands of the Client now.
If you want a value from Choices to affect the composition of your Form, you have to send this value as part of the request that will get your Form and in the process determine what your Form will look like.
myForm = loanform()
if request.GET["choice"] == "emi": # [1]
    del myForm.emi

[1] This example assumes that the Client will send a query parameter "choice" as part of the GET request.
